# Exporting data from Grid View to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, closedxml

I am trying to save data from grid view to excel using `ClosedXML`, although I have managed to do so successfully, but it is saving only a single page of Grid view , how can I save the data of all the pages of grid view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052998/exporting-datagridview-to-excel-in-c-sharp/39053359#39053359

Answer (score -1):

Its really easy, you just need to add datatable as a worksheet

Exact solution for your problem can be found below:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-data-to-multiple-Sheets-Worksheets-of-Excel-file-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx.

Please let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

thanks
karthik